# MySQL Stored Procedure doesn't work

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Why this statement returns `NULL`?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS hr.Test;
CREATE PROCEDURE hr.`Test`
           (
             IN `empID` BIGINT(20)
           , IN untill date
           , IN `salaryType` INT(10)
           )
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
  select untill;
END;

call Test(2, '2014-01', 2);
```

It's strange since when I want to return value of `empID` or `salaryType` it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple reason because `'2014-01'` is an invalid date and so it returns `null`. To prove that try the below query and it will return `null`

```
select cast('2014-01' as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `'2014-01'` is not a date, `'2014-01-01'` would be one. You are missing the day component of a date.

Comment: OMG What a concentration :) ,